# Are questions of the form 'How do I wire…' on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, on-off-topic

The Help Center defines a few on-topic subjects:

> If you have a questions that addresses a specific Raspberry Pi topic, then this is the right Stack Exchange site for you!
>
> For the most part this includes:
>
> - Raspberry Pi hardware, including GPIO and other related electronics.
> - Raspberry Pi peripherals
> - Software that runs on the Raspberry Pi
> - Operating Systems built for the Raspberry Pi

Suppose I have a question on how to wire a specific component, but that component is not specific to the Raspberry Pi (even though the Pi is being used to control it).
Is such a question on-topic?

**Example:**

> How do I connect a PIR motion sensor to the Raspberry Pi?

<sub>This isn't an example out of thin air; you can assume that [some tutorials](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-12-sensing-movement) have been worked through unsuccessfully.</sub>

Answer (score 4):

I'm afraid there's no clear answer to this question. All I can say is that **it depends**.

This would be my general test for off-topic'ness:

- If the Raspberry Pi is involved in your question in such a way that knowledge of the Pi, not just of the sub-topic (*in this case electronics*), would benefit the answer then this is probably the right place for that question.
- If the question could be better answered by someone with a more in-depth knowledge of the sub-topic (*such as [Electronics.SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) for this*), then you're probably better off asking it there.

Comment: Though the example he gives would be on topic right?

Comment: @Loko Yes, that's right.

Comment: Related: [Are hardware hacks on-topic](http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/557/are-hardware-hacks-off-topic)